# Vertx blocking handler when pulling from a database

Tags: java, database, http, vert.x

For my web application, I need to serve dynamic HTML pages using templates and static css and JavaScript files. Except every one of my dynamic HTML pages would need to pull from a database and block the thread on the event loop. So in this case I would have to use a blocking handler for every single one of the routes/pages. My question is, is this proper at all? And would this help for many users accessing the website at one time?

Also, if I want to use my own JDBC client, rather than one provided by Vertx, can I just use that? (E.g. Use HikariCP for my project and use that independent of Vertx)

Comment: What do you meant by: `Except every one of my dynamic HTML pages would need to pull from a database and block the thread on the event loop`?

Comment: I mean, the information/content of the page needs to be pulled from a database and inserted using a template engine such as free marker.

Comment: Then I don't think you need to "block" the event loop, of course depending on what you end up using to access the database. Just receive the request, "build" the Web page (fetching the content from the database, insert the values accordingly) and send it back to the user-agent.

Comment: So you are saying that pulling from a database does not block the thread?

Comment: Yes and no. I said: `of course depending on what you end up using to access the database`. If you use, for instance, the Vert.x JDBC client it won't block the event loop.

Answer (score 0):

First of all HikariCP is just another pool provider for Vertx. So you can just use it with Vertx client.

http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-jdbc-client/java/

And if you use Vertx JDBC client, you don't need to block anything at all. 
What it would look like is:

```
router
   db (callback)
      freemaker (callback)
         puts the result back on response
```

See this official example:
https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/blob/3.3.0/web-examples/src/main/java/io/vertx/example/web/templating/freemarker/Server.java

Notice how engine is being used. In your case, you may wrap everything from `ctx.put("name", "Vert.x Web")` in a DB callback, and set context accordingly.

Comment: @Petersoj, no, callbacks let your event loop deal with other stuff until the response arrives.